# How to plot precision and recall of multiclass classifier?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, roc, precision-recall

I'm using scikit learn, and I want to plot the precision and recall curves. the classifier I'm using is `RandomForestClassifier`. All the resources in the documentations of scikit learn uses binary classification. Also, can I plot a ROC curve for multiclass?

Also, I only found for SVM for multilabel and it has a `decision_function` which `RandomForest` doesn't have

Comment: There is a paragraph with example here:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html.   Is that not what you want?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/auto_examples/plot_precision_recall.html

Comment: @Yohst that example uses svm with decision function, and RandomForest doesn't have decision functions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From scikit-learn documentation:

- [Precision-Recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html):

> Precision-recall curves are typically used in binary classification to
> study the output of a classifier. In order to extend the
> precision-recall curve and average precision to multi-class or
> multi-label classification, it is necessary to binarize the output.
> One curve can be drawn per label, but one can also draw a
> precision-recall curve by considering each element of the label
> indicator matrix as a binary prediction (micro-averaging).

- [Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html):

> ROC curves are typically used in binary classification to study the
> output of a classifier. In order to extend ROC curve and ROC area to
> multi-class or multi-label classification, it is necessary to binarize
> the output. One ROC curve can be drawn per label, but one can also
> draw a ROC curve by considering each element of the label indicator
> matrix as a binary prediction (micro-averaging).

Therefore, you should binarize the output and consider precision-recall and roc curves for each class. Moreover, you are going to use [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) to get class probabilities.

I divide the code into three parts:

1. general settings, learning and prediction
2. precision-recall curve
3. ROC curve

**1. general settings, learning and prediction**

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, roc_curve
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline

mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784")
y = mnist.target
y = y.astype(np.uint8)
n_classes = len(set(y))

Y = label_binarize(mnist.target, classes=[*range(n_classes)])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mnist.data,
                                                    Y,
                                                    random_state = 42)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50,
                             max_depth=3,
                             random_state=0))
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_score = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

**2. precision-recall curve**

```
# precision recall curve
precision = dict()
recall = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    precision[i], recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test[:, i],
                                                        y_score[:, i])
    plt.plot(recall[i], precision[i], lw=2, label='class {}'.format(i))
    
plt.xlabel("recall")
plt.ylabel("precision")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.title("precision vs. recall curve")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**3. ROC curve**

```
# roc curve
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()

for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i],
                                  y_score[:, i]))
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], lw=2, label='class {}'.format(i))

plt.xlabel("false positive rate")
plt.ylabel("true positive rate")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.title("ROC curve")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: why i'm using OneVsRestClassifier? isn't RandomForest already support multiclass?

Comment: I have those errors when I run the first part:
UserWarning: Label not 0 is present in all training example
UserWarning: Label not 1 is present in all training example
UserWarning: Label not 2 is present in all training example

Comment: Please, note that a warning is NOT an error. Considering this line `Y = label_binarize(mnist.target, classes=[*range(n_classes)])`, you should provide the classes in your dataset. In my example, the classes are `[0,1,2,...,9]`.

Comment: How do you create PR curve or a ROC curve with the micro-average? As far as I know, if you have 3 classes, you would obtain 3 probability vectors, 1 with the probability of each class. And then the observation gets assigned to the class with the highest probability. That is, independent of a threshold. But for ROC and PR curves, you need a threshold, so how would you do the microaverage? how to you assign an observation to class based on a specific threshold?

Comment: I just tried to reverse calculate the precision and recall when the threshold is equal to 0 and see if it matches the one given by the classification_report() function but it returns strangely different results. I am addressing this problem here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559203/why-does-precision-recall-curve-return-similar-but-not-equal-values-than-confu?noredirect=1#comment1028225_559203

Comment: @JohnSall Replace label_binarize line with Y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0,1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9])