# How to plot OvO precision recall curve for a multi-class classifier?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, precision, roc

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090541/how-to-plot-precision-and-recall-of-multiclass-classifier?rq=3) , the precision recall curve is calculated for each class. So, can we calculate precision recall auc like OvO auc roc? How can we combine class 0 and 1 just like the graph ([in this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)) and then get ovo precision recall auc? [image: OvO auc]